# Would it be possible to create a Lucas-Lehmer-like test for primes of the form$ 3^{n}-2$

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I was thinking maybe this could be a proof formed around $(3+\sqrt7 )(3-\sqrt7)$ instead of $(2-\sqrt3)(2+\sqrt3)$, but I don't know. I'm not an expert on this by any stretch, just curious.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I will point out this sequence of primes is on the OEIS at A014224 and A014232. Interestingly, there also seems to be a generalization of the Euclid-Euler theorem for perfect numbers using these primes.

Comment: All the Lucas tests I am aware of allow a primality proof of $N$ is $N+1$ can be completely factored. So I doubt that there is such an analogue test.

Comment: @Peter  factor $N-1$ into $3(3^{n-1}-1)$ then apply the $M+1$ test on the cofactor ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Nice idea, but I do not think that this is possible. If I did not seriously misunderstand the $N-1$ and the $N+1$ method, the original number must have the property that $N-1$ or $N+1$ can be completely factored (or at least enough factors can be found) and not one of the factors of $N-1$ or $N+1$. Of course, if this were possible, we could prove much more huge numbers to be prime.

Comment: $3^{n-1}$ to fully factor $(3^{n-1}-1)$ then use the factorization to apply $N-1$ on the original number ...

Comment: We cannot efficiently factor $M=3^{n-1}-1$ in general by using that $M+1=3^{n-1}$ has a trivial factorization. The $N+1$-method and the $N-1$-method can only be applied AFTER we have determined the factorization of one of those numbers or at least a sufficient partial factorization.

Comment: Express them in Riesel or Serpinski form maybe ?

Comment: All 2 mod 6( except 2), 3 mod 4, 14 mod 16, and 7 mod 18 values of $n$ are out  As they have factors 7,5,17,19 respectively ...